# Have upstart read environment from /etc/environment for a service

Tags: upstart

What is the best way to provide the environment variables defined in `/etc/environment` to an [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) service?

I think simply sourcing them with `.` in a script section does not work, because the scripts are executed by `sh` which would need an additional `export` in front of every definition...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally got an answer on the `#upstart` IRC channel. At some point, upstart will get proper PAM support and thus read `/etc/environment` itself. Until then, the trick is to execute the command with su. `su` uses PAM and will set up the proper environment. Example:

```
script 
    exec su root -c /usr/sbin/job_needing_envs
end script
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer, you've helped me in exactly the same issue.

Comment: error: `su: must be run from a terminal`

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use `eval $(cat /etc/environment | sed 's/^/export /')`

It takes each line in `/etc/environment`, prepends `export`, and evaluates it:

```
script
exec /bin/bash <<'EOT'
  eval $(cat /etc/environment | sed 's/^/export /')
  do_what_you_need_to
EOT
end script
```

Comment: Why do you use exec and not just put the export directly in the script block?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your script:

```
. /etc/environment
export VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
```

where the variables you need are specified in place of the "VAR1" style placeholders.

Comment: That way I have to manually keep the upstart configuration and /etc/environment in sync, which is (in my opinion) not any better than defining the variables twice...

Comment: I wouldn't use `/etc/environment` to define all your needed variables.   Leave that as a static file. On my system, I could only find a few scripts that use it anyway. Create a file called something like `/etc/environment.local` and put your variables *and* exports in there and source *that* file. Then you only have to maintain that *one* file.

Comment: /etc/environment is read by pam_env.so (and not by any scripts), so it is available for any login. Only programs started by upstart don't have access to that file by defaulht, unfortunately.